# Fabric js clip object to background image

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working on fabric js and I have encountered a problem where i have to clip user added object (text, image, svg etc) to background image set in canvas. The background image could be png or svg(with multiple path). The background image is of non-uniform shape, such as leaf, shirt etc.

How could it be done?

Comment: your question is completely unacceptable, sorry; http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Litchi_chinensis_leaf.png',
  function(img){
img.scale(0.3);
canvas.setBackgroundImage(img);
canvas.renderAll();
  }
);

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width:80, height:100, fill:'red',
  globalCompositeOperation: 'source-atop',
  top: 100
});
canvas.add(rect);

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius:80, height:100, fill:'blue',
  globalCompositeOperation: 'source-atop'
});
canvas.add(circle);
circle.center().setCoords();
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width="500" height="400" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

This snippet shows you what is doable. Is not easy to clip with an "image". What you can do is use globalCompositeOperation as i show you.

As you see rect and circle are visible only over the background and not outside.

If you want using another value other than "source-atop" you can obtain different effects. With "source-in" the background will be transparent and will serve the only porpouse of "clipping" the area

Comment: @AdreaBogazzi is it possible with text object too ?

Comment: text object in the ground or foreground?

Comment: anyway it is possible both to clip an image using text as a shape OR chip text using image as a shape.

Comment: I used globalCompositeOperation but is not working if you check example i given

Comment: Please, open another stack overflow question, explain that you took code from this answer and you cannot make it work. I'm willing to help, but i need a simple model "question + example with failing code" i do not have so much free time.

Comment: @AdreaBogazzi here is my question and my failing code. Can you please take look i just want it similar to image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833992/masking-image-and-text-in-fabric-js